# Minha div ultrapassa a div pai mesmo eu colocando width 100%

Tags: css

estou com uma duvida, tenho um botão porem ele ultrapassa a div pai, mesmo eu colocando a div pai com "position:relative" e o "right:100%" do botão.... alguem sabe dizer oq esta errado para o botão estar ultrapassando a div pai ? se eu colocar o right:50% ele não ultrapassa a div pai

```js
function toogle(){
    document.querySelector('#toogle').classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#toogle{
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.822);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 45vh;
    border-radius: 160px;
    box-shadow: 
                inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position: relative;
    transition:.5s;
}

#button{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black,
                inset 0 4px 4px gray,
                inset 0 -4px 4px gray;
    transition: .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#toogle.active #button{
   left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Dark theme</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="toogle">

        <div onclick="toogle()" id="button">

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está considerando o tamanho do botão. Adicionando `left: 100%;` você implementa a largura total do "toggle" a esquerda do botão. Para resolver esse problema, você deve pegar o tamanho do botão e subtrair pelo tamanho total do "toggle".

O "toggle" tem 400px de largura e o botão 200px, isso significa que o botão mede exatamente 50% da largura do "toggle", por isso que quando você coloca `left: 50%` o botão se move apropriadamente.

Veja:

```js
function toogle() {
  document.querySelector('#toogle').classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#toogle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.822);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 45vh;
  border-radius: 160px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black, inset 0 4px 4px gray, inset 0 -4px 4px gray;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toogle.active #button {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Dark theme</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="toogle">

    <div onclick="toogle()" id="button">

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Você também pode optar por adicionar exatamente 200px:

```js
function toogle() {
  document.querySelector('#toogle').classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#toogle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.822);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 45vh;
  border-radius: 160px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 8px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black, inset 0 4px 4px gray, inset 0 -4px 4px gray;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toogle.active #button {
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Dark theme</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="toogle">

    <div onclick="toogle()" id="button">

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ótimo , poxa muito obrigado Nicolas, agora uma ultima duvida, para alterar as cores dos elementos `html`, eu posso através do `javascript` alterar o arquivo `css` importado?

Comment: Sim. Usando JS tu consegue tranquilo alterar o estilo CSS, mesmo que ele esteja sendo importado de outros documentos. Você só vai precisar estudar um pouco a respeito, mas não é muito complicado.